# EF Core SQL multiple config options

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following config in startup.cs to setup EF Core with MS SQL:

```
         services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                           x => x.UseNetTopologySuite()
                    );
            });
```

I need to increase the timeout because there are some long running queries that will be executed. I understand that I need to add the following, but not sure how to incorporate it into my existing options.UseSqlServer

```
             x => x.CommandTimeout(300)
```

Comment: You can also set `Timeout` property into your connection string like this fashion `Server=YourServerName;Database=yourDb;Trusted_connection=true;connect timeout=300;`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this via the connection string.

```
"Data Source=SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=true;Command Timeout=300"
```

Or like this

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    this.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnectionString"),
    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60))
);
```

Comment: with the second method, how would I include the UseNetTopologySuite() option

Comment: Hm, not entirely sure. Why not use the first method? Why adamant on using the second way?

Comment: Get an error adding it to the connection string: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'command timeout'.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add multiple options:

```
services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer("connectionString", sqlOptions => 
    {
        sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(60);
        sqlOptions.UseNetTopologySuite();
    }));
```